# Show td as rows - display table row not working

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-tables

I have a year calendar that shows just the way I want on normal browsers, but in responsive browser I want it to show all the months below each other, due to layout problems.

I know how to apply code to responsive browser - this is not what I am asking about.

I tried giving the td's the value of `display:table-row`, and its giving me almost the desired result .. it keeps pushing the rows to left and wont accept `width:100%` value, that's the problem.

Here is a link to the website I am working with [www.5eren.dk](http://5eren.dk/kalender/aar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set `display:table` on `<tr>` and set `display:table-row` on `<td>`. use this CSS:

```
.year-view>table>tbody>tr {
display: table;
width: 100%;
}
.year-view>table>tbody>tr>td {
display: table-row;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! you saved my butt there .. i dont quite understand the > mark in css i thought it was just by adding classes after eachother .. i will make more research into the greater than sign .. once again thank you, i appreciate it

Comment: @Sillo your welcome, you can read more about selectors here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors